# How to optimize postgresql query

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-performance

This query takes 13 seconds to execute, but if I remove the **gln is not null** condition , it will take 2 seconds to execute, why and how to optimize the query?
**EXPLAIN:**.
https://explain.depesz.com/s/cn8H (with gln check)
vs.
https://explain.depesz.com/s/OJap (without gln chck)

```
select "nomenclatureKindGuid1C"
from "mds_nomenclature"
where exists(select *
             from "mds_nomenclature_contractor"
             where "mds_nomenclature"."guid1C" = "mds_nomenclature_contractor"."nomenclatureGuid1C"
               and exists(select *
                          from "mds_contractor"
                          where "mds_nomenclature_contractor"."contractorGuid1C" =
                                "mds_contractor"."guid1C"
                            and "gln" is not null)
               and exists(select *
                          from "mds_price"
                          where "mds_nomenclature_contractor"."guid1C" =
                                "mds_price"."nomenclatureContractorGuid1C"
                            and (("finalVersion" = true and
                                  ("contractorGuid1C" is null or
                                   ("contractorGuid1C" = '0004983d-1d4c-11e9-80c9-0050568b6b27')) and
                                  ("objectGuid1C" is null or
                                   ("objectGuid1C" = 'ae4e3474-7c0d-4ae4-80cb-524ab67b001f')) and
                                  ("purchasePlanDocumentGuid1C" is null or exists(select *
                                                                                  from "mds_purchase_plan_document"
                                                                                  where "mds_price"."purchasePlanDocumentGuid1C" =
                                                                                        "mds_purchase_plan_document"."guid1C"
                                                                                    and "startDate" <= '2020-02-10 18:25:04'
                                                                                    and "endDate" >= '2020-02-10 18:25:04'))))
                            and "mds_nomenclature_contractor"."deleted" is null)
          )
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you, I'll prefer lower case column/table names, but the structure above was created by another developer

Comment: In the first explain, this part of the sql seems to be missing: `and "contractor"."deleted" is null` ?

Comment: @Luuk i've updated the question with new explains.
the condition doesn't change anything, it still 13 seconds vs 2

Comment: Please take a look at the plans, and do a search for `mds_contractor`. In the first plan you will find 4 hits, in the second 13 hits, with one of them referring to `deleted`.

Comment: @Luuk but without deleted condition it still takes 13 seconds to execute

Comment: Your plans don't line up with your queries.  The table names are different, and "gln" doesn't show up anywhere in the slow plan.

Comment: Yes, we need the plans for *exactly* the query you are showing. Also, how is the index `test` defined?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I've updated the post

Answer (score 0):

In some of these cases, the first step I take is to create a temporary table with the tuples I need to compare (because it seems a complex comparison), and then I build the whole statement.